# How to get paid invoice collection filter by payment method

Tags: invoice, sales-order

How can I get invoice collection filter by status paid & payment method ?

I know how to filter order collection by payment method

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders->getSelect()->join(
    array('payment' =>  $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')),
    'payment.parent_id = main_table.entity_id',
    array('*')
);
$orders->addFieldToFilter('method','ccsave');
```

But I can't make it work with

```
Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();
```

where invoice status is also paid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::STATE_PAID);
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('P' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')),"P.parent_id = main_table.order_id",array('method'=>'P.method'));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('method', 'checkmo');
echo '<pre>';
foreach($collection as $invoice) {
    print_r($invoice);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Magento User Guide: "*Invoice is a record of the receipt of payment for an order*" there is no need to apply paid filter to invoice collection. Please refer [**Magento Guide**](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/order-processing/order-invoice.html) for further details.

However, if you want to get invoice collection by payment method you can use below code.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();
$orders->getSelect()->join(
    array('payment' =>  $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')),
    'payment.parent_id = main_table.order_id',
    array('*')
);
$orders->addFieldToFilter('method','ccsave');  // Set you payment method here
```